# Qt software crashing on USB events, such as USB device insertion or mouse movement

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, x11

I am working on this project which is already running nicely from a long time. The users only complain about software crashing when they insert a USB device, or by passing the mouse cursor on an specific button.

I have no idea what's going on as our software throws an unknown exception.

The exception thrown is the following:

```
exception unknown: (14QMetaCallEvent, 43, ,14QXcbConnection)
```

The exception code:

```
QString("[EXIT]{%1/%2} - exception unknown: (%3, %4, %5, %6)")
                                        .arg(user)
                                        .arg(userID)
                                        .arg(typeid(*qEvent).name())
                                        .arg(qEvent->type())
                                        .arg(qPrintable(qObject->objectName()))
                                        .arg(typeid(*qObject).name());
```

Should I be concerned about linux library on USB, such as libusb or libinput? We ship our software for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you try/manage to reproduce the bug in debug mode?

Comment: Check on every pointer used: might be null.